# ios use multiple third party framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I Use Two third party framework.

```
SIPPhone (SIPphone.framework)
RealtimeVideo (H264Play.a,netsdk.a)
```

These framework work fine on single project.
Than I these framework added to one project

First App SIPPhone is work fine ,
but Enter RealtimeVideo page .APP will crash.

So I try to `Build->Setting` `"other linker flags"`.
Added to  `-ObjC` , `-force_load`,... etc.

```
Xcode have display errors. 223 duplicate symbols for architecture i386.
Ex:
duplicate symbol _ff_inverse in:
 /Users/sonas/Desktop/jackyfile/CCTVtest/SIPLib.framework/PortSIPLib(PortSIPLib)
 /Users/sonas/Desktop/jackyfile/CCTVtest/CCTVtest/H264Play.a(mathtables.o)
```

Please , give me some advice. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issues of duplicate symbol for architecture i386 has been discussed in a different stack overflow section. Sharing the link for your reference.

[6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520921/6-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

Comment: thank , But I didn't rename duplicate .h or .m file . These duplicate symbols file in  framework  and .a file.

Comment: Can you check Target - > Build phases- >Link Binary with Libraries. If any duplicate lib is present from the framework and remove them.