# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, paypal, paytm

I Want to Integrate [PayTmSDk](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit) in my app. But Im getting error while building.

ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Tried Removing -Objc flag from otherlinker flags, Im able to build, but I'm using [PayPalSdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) also which needs to add -Objc flag to other linker flags.

Please help me..

Thank you..

Comment: read this line 'duplicate symbols for architecture' you have some object/class more than one time

Comment: @Gagan_iOS How to find those object/class

Comment: you have to check your code carefully. No option as per my knowledge

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Just Removing PayTm Sdk the error was gone, but how to make it compatible for my project

Comment: ok..read & follow steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang      and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520921/6-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Didn't Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

paytm also contain some reachability classes due to which duplicate error of reachability.o error comes;  removed reachability.m from compile resources.